# Escape HTML entities in JSON

Tags: php, json

My JSON result http://daysof.me/lowyat/list.php

What I did:

```
$num = 0;
$array = array();
foreach($rows as $go){

    if($num == count($rows)-1){break;}

    $reply = $go->find('td',3)->plaintext;//replies
    $starter = $go->find('td',4)->plaintext;//starter
    $views = $go->find('td',5)->plaintext;//views
    $action = $go->find('td',6)->plaintext;//last action
    $desc = $go->find('td',2)->find('div div',2)->plaintext;//description
    $title = $go->find('td',2)->find('div div a',0)->plaintext;//topic name
    $link = $go->find('td',2)->find('div div a',0)->href;

    $array[]= array(
        'title'=>$title,
        'desc'=>$desc,
        'starter'=>trim($starter),
        'replies'=>trim($reply),
        'url'=>'https://forum.lowyat.net'.$link
    );

    $num ++;
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

You'll see some single quote been turned into `&quot;` and ampersand gave strange code.

How can I escape that? I tried `'title'=>htmlentities($title)` still no luck with that.

Comment: What are you doing with `$num`..? A foreach loops through all items and stops automatically... Also, don't forget the correct Content-type: `header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf8')`

Comment: @Rudie is that enough to solve my problem?

Comment: Probably not, but they both make it and you better. The result works for me now btw. Parsing works and I see no `&quot;` anymore.

Comment: @Rudie but in my ajax callback there is still strange codes..

Comment: And you should never have to escape anything in JSON. PHP's `json_encode` will take care of all that.

Comment: Maybe your AJAX callback is wrong. The JSON is correct, although it still needs a correct `Content-type`, which might fix your AJAX callback if you're using jQuery.

Comment: @Rudie it doesn't work with merely set the header

Comment: Just use html_entity_decode() whenever you need to display the data and the string equivalents will be converted to html characters.

Comment: Content type is still `text/html`, without charset. Don't use html encoding or decoding. You want the literal values in JSON, not encoded or decoded into something else.